# Why $-2Ric=\mathcal{L}_vg$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

$\varphi_t$ is a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms generated by a vector field $V$ on $M$,

$$
g_{ij}=\varphi_t^*g_{ij}(x,0) ~~~
\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t}=-2R_{ij}
$$

How to show that $-2Ric=\mathcal{L}_vg$ ? The $\mathcal{L}_vg$ is Lie derivative

I only have a little knowledge of Riemannian geometry and PDE.But I must read some paper about Ricci flow .What should do? What book I should read before read Ricci flow? Thanks for any helping .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have it! I assume $v$ in your Lie derivative is the vector field tangent to the orbits of $\phi_t$. If that is the case then $v=\partial/\partial_t$ and the Lie derivative of $g_{ab}$ is just $\partial_t g_{ab}$.

I do not know about Ricci flow in particular, but I suggest you get a good grounding in differential and Riemannian geometry first. For a general introduction to differential geometry I would look at [Tu’s Introduction to Manifolds](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Manifolds-Universitext-Loring-W-ebook/dp/B014P9I1MU/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1444132406&sr=8-2&keywords=tu+differential+geometry) or [Lee’s Smooth manifolds](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1441999817/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1444132426&sr=8-3&keywords=lee+differential+geometry). For Riemannian geometry therea re good books by John Lee again or Do Carmo.

Comment: How compute $\mathcal{L}_vg_{ij}=g_{ij}\nabla_jV^k+g_{jk}\nabla_iV^k$?

Comment: I think it should be $\mathcal{L}_vg_{ij}=g_{ij}\nabla_jV^k+g_{jk}\nabla_iV^k+V^k\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}$, but the it is above one on the book.